# Non-English characters in URLs with Biblatex-Chicago + Biber

Tags: biblatex, biber, unicode, urls, cyrillic

Is there any way to keep the URLs in the same form they are saved within the `.bib` files when using `biblatex-chicago` with Biber? For instance, the entry

```
@misc{RussianEmpire.1855,
 author = {Russian Empire},
 year = {1855},
 title = {Treaty of Shimoda},
 url = {https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/Симодский_договор_с_Японией_(1855)},
}
```

results in the following output:

[image]

While there certain are benefits to converting the link itself, this sort of output in the footnote makes it both ugly and difficult to re-enter the link when reading a printed copy. How would one proceed about to receive the output along the lines of "[https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/Санкт-Петербургский_договор_с_Японией_(1875)](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%81_%D0%AF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9_(1875))"?

Minimal working example:

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[russian,british]{babel}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic]{CMU Serif} 
\usepackage[CJK, Cyrillics]{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionsForCyrillics{\russianfont}{}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[labeldate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[unicode,hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@misc{RussianEmpire.1855,
 author = {Russian Empire},
 year = {1855},
 title = {Treaty of Shimoda},
 url = {https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/Симодский_договор_с_Японией_(1855)},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Cyrillics support test: Тест\\

\cite{RussianEmpire.1855}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You should make a complete example. This would make tests much easier.

Comment: Maybe when you copy and past, you (youre OS or whatever) change the encoding. Try a encoding-decoding software like http://www.asiteaboutnothing.net/c_decode-url.html

Comment: Added minimal working example illustrating the problem.

Comment: biber URI encodes all URLS. Version 2.7, currently in development on Sourceforge, adds a new option `--nouri-encode` which disables URI encoding. This requires version 3.7 of biblatex, also in development.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, PLK. Good to have it narrowed down. :)

Comment: @PLK I have added a CW answer, if you'd like to add an answer yourself, I will try to remove the CW answer.

Answer (score 3):

Biber 2.7 introduces a new option to disable URI encoding of URLs, use the switch

```
--nouri-encode
```

when you compile with Biber.