# BibLaTeX escaping URL to %xx, but I want to write Unicode address

Tags: biblatex, urls

I'm using `biblatex` with `biber`.  When I want to write into `.bib` url, for example `url = {ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ветроэнергетика}`, into the output pdf the link looks like `ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%B0...`, so, link is encoded.

I want the link into the bibliography looks like into the `.bib` file with UTF-8 symbols `ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ветроэнергетика`.  How this could be done?

Comment: You need the development version of bibkatex. See the comment of plk here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332563/non-english-characters-in-urls-with-biblatex-chicago-biber.